# Change the type of an imported JSON in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, import

When importing a JSON file in a TypeScript project with the `resolveJsonModule` option enabled the TypeScript compiler is able to automatically infer the type of the imported JSON file. However, this type is too specific and I want to replace it with a more generic one. I tried to do this by writing a custom type definitions file:

```js
// file modules.d.ts

declare module "*.json" {
  const value: Record<string, string>;
  export default value;
}
```

but the TypeScript compiler ignores this definition.

The only way that works for me is to use temporary variables, like this:

```js
import DATA_JSON from "./data.json";

const DATA  = DATA_JSON as Record<string, string>; // Use my own type instead of the inferred one.

export { DATA };
```

but this is boring. Is there any other way to give my own types to JSON files imported in TypeScript?

Comment: Did add `modules.d.ts` to `include` in your tsconfig? Do it, if not, because if you didn't, typescript will not see this file, because you do not import it explicitly. Also you could write `///<reference path="path/to/modules.d.ts" />` in the beginning of this second file where you import json

Comment: I tried something similar but no joy. I wanted to reference an interface I am already using elsewhere in my app. `src` is in `include` in `tsconfig.json`. Code: https://gist.github.com/gknapp/22dd80ecd3a29e685e4b43d2fed2874d

Answer (score -4):

you could try it with **mapped types**. Not sure what structure/types you want to achieve but I believe it's the way to go.

Having such requirement sounds like a good moment to start exploring advanced TS (I recommend **Matt Pocock** on yt)

```
import DATA_JSON from './data.json';

const OWN_TYPED_DATA_JSON = DATA_JSON as unknown as {
   [key in keyof typeof DATA_JSON]: {
      [nestedKey in keyof typeof DATA_JSON[key]]: {
         [moreNestedKey in keyof typeof DATA_JSON[key][nestedKey]]: string
      }
   }
}
```